# MvcCodeRouting MapCodeRoutes in separate assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use `MvcCodeRouting` in a project which has controllers in more than one assembly:

```
routes.MapCodeRoutes(typeof(Controllers.HomeController));
```

I house controllers in more than one assembly but the [Getting Started](https://github.com/maxtoroq/MvcCodeRouting/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started.md)
says that all controllers must be in the same assembly as the root controller passed to `MapCodeRoutes`.

Can I call `MapCodeRoutes` >1 time, once for each assembly I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call `MapCodeRoutes` as many times as you want. If there are controllers with the same name in different assemblies, you can use the `baseRoute` parameter. See [Split a large application into various projects](https://github.com/maxtoroq/MvcCodeRouting/blob/master/docs/Base-Route.md#split-a-large-application-into-various-projects).